# На ноутбуке виснет Kubuntu

Tags: linux, железо, kde, kubuntu

Всем привет!
После установки Kubuntu на ноутбук Acer Extensa система виснет каждые 5-10 минут. Ничего кроме жесткого ребута не помогает.
Как быть? Как решить проблему?

Comment: Смотрите что в логах написано...

Comment: Какая видеокарта и какие драйверы на неё установлены?

Comment: Видео: mesa dri intel(r) bay trail